# How does one persist the `launchctl limit` in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: osx-yosemite, ulimit, launchctl

There's a note in the `launchctl` man pages stating that:

> launchctl no longer has an interactive mode, nor does it accept
>   commands from stdin. The **/etc/launchd.conf file is no longer consulted**
>   for subcommands to run during early boot time; this functionality was
>   removed for security considerations.

Is there another way to persist `launchctl limit` configuration? E.g., `launchctl limit maxproc 1024` and `launchctl limit maxfiles 4096`